# i want to make an automatic signal according to it's task date in JBPM

Tags: jbpm

i want to make an automatic signal according to it's task date in JBPM.  Can i use decision node for implementing this situation? if no any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [timer](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v3/userguide/jpdl.html#timer.element) with a transition defined

Comment: yes, and i found that there is problem with EL in version 3.0.9